# Algorithm for balancing samples in real time

Tags: python, r, algorithms

Let's say I'm conducting a survey with a desired number of participants (`n = 100`). The people who take my survey can either be male or female and I'd like there to be a 50/50 balance along males and females who take my survey.

If I knew that there were exactly twice as many females as males in this population, I could simply randomly turn away half the females that line up to take my survey. However, what if I don't know what the actual proportion of males and females are in the population? How do I decide with what probability to turn away either males/females?

One trivial solution is to accept some fraction of the participants (say n/10), and compute the breakdown in proportion. I then inversely weight the probability of selecting males or females in the next n/10 participants by their representation in the preceding slice.

But I'm wondering if there's an optimal approach that guarantees convergence at the desired level of representation (e.g. half males / half females) for a given sample size (`n`) as quickly as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Include people with 100% probability until their category fills up. Keep track of the total number seen so far per category. Then, on seeing the k'th person in a full category, we include it in our sample with probability target/k.

E.g. We want 50 men and 50 women. On seeing the 51st man, we include him in our sample 50/51 of the time (replacing a random member of the sample). The next man gets included 50/52 of the time, and so on. When we include someone in the sample past our target, we bump a random person from the sample.

At the end, each person that could be in our sample is in our sample with probability (sample)/(category population).

Let's say our target sample size per category is r. After we see k people for k >= r, each of the k people we've seen should be in our population with probability r/k. It's easy to show this is true for k=r, and a simple proof by induction shows this continues to be true as k grows. Basically, at each step an element is *not* kicked out of the pool with probability 1 - (r/(k+1)) * (1/r) = 1 - 1/(k+1) = k/(k+1). Thus the probability of an element surviving for the time-to-date goes to r/k * k/(k+1) = r/(k+1).

Comment: What do you mean by "bump a random person from the sample." In this case, you can't do that since they've already been surveyed at that point, and you've wasted money on them.

Comment: What you could do is include people with 100% probability until their category fills up, and then *only* accept people from the other category, kicking everybody else out. But then you get "clumping" at the end where a disproportionate amount of the other category will be surveyed later in time relative to the other ones. You want to do your best to avoid that

Comment: @Parseltongue There will be some wasted surveys, but the growth of waste drops very quickly. E.g. if we want 50 and the population is 137 then we expect 100 surveys. It takes a population of 1014 to get us to 200 surveys, and 7495 to get us to 300, and 55,381 to 400.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. That's helpful. Thanks! At $50.00 a survey, just need to make sure there's as little waste as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't need a sample that's representative of the population. You just need a sample that contains an equal number of both genders. If that is what it is, from the survey you have collected over the period of time, you could simply see the class with the least count and randomly select as many observations of the other class.

**Sample size (n) unknown:**

For example, your survey has 40 females and 45 males. Randomly select 40 males from the 45. This will give you a sample (since the population was not surveyed) that has an equal number of males and females.

**Sample size (n) known:**

If you know the size of the sample (**n**), then you can randomly pick half the sample size from both the genders provided the survey has at least as many observations from each of the genders as the half of sample size.

For example, n = 100 and you need 50 males and 50 females.

If the survey has >=50 observations from each of the two genders, you can randomly pick 50 from each of the genders.

If one of the genders' count is <50, you'll have to survey a bit longer (until the bare minimum is met) or reduce your sample size.

**In general**, we cannot tell the population proportion unless we survey each and every individual which could be a huge burden on the resources. So, we instead survey randomly selected areas and try to estimate the population proportion based on the sample.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're misunderstanding the problem. Imagine we have a line of people outside our house. Some male, some female. All of them wanting to do a survey. Each person in line I need to decide if I'm going to accept / reject them from taking the survey. I wanted an algorithm that could minimize the number of rejections, while achieving perfect balance along males/female for a given N.

Comment: On what basis are you going to turn them away? Age? Height? or something else? what is the filter?

Comment: Are you trying to have 50% of both genders in the line at any time? Is that it?

Comment: Their gender... If my N = 100 and I want 50 males and 50 females, and  it's a 90/10 split of males and females in the population, I shouldn't accept every male since I'll oversample. I'd need to reject some fraction of the males to create real-time balance.

Comment: It doesn't need to be "at any time." It needs to be "by the time I get to my desired N." And I want to minimize the total number of rejections

Comment: Alright. Think about it like this. There are already 100 people in the line. 90 males and 10 females. At the time you reach the line you need only 10 males and 10 females. You could randomly pick 10 females and all the males. Reject the rest. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Prateek, you can't see the line. You don't get the luxury of randomly picking 10 females/males.  They appear before you and you decide whether to accept or reject. Your goal is to balance the sample along some desired balance (e.g. 50/50) by the time you get to N -- your desired sampling size. You should minimize rejections and also make sure that you don't get all your females/males at one point in time (e.g. the very end)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225808/discussion-between-prateek-and-parseltongue).